# Linear Search in a Char Array -- C++ (Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: c++, arrays, search, visual-c++-2005

I am very new to C++ programming and you will see why.

I want to make a character array consisting of a few words that I want to search with a linear search function. Does this array have to be a two-dimensional array? For example:

```
char Colors[3][6] = {"red", "green", "blue"};
```

I tried it like this:

```
char Colors[] = {"red", "green", "blue"};
```

This gave me a "too many initializers" error.

I assume the 1st method is correct because it states the amount of elements in the array and the maximum length of an element, correct?

Now how would I implement a linear search function to find a word inside that array? Can I do something like the following:

(Assuming the linearSearch function has already been declared)

```
char searchKey;  
char element;

char Colors[3][6] = {"red", "green", "blue"};

printf("Enter the color to look for: \n");

scanf("%s", searchKey);

element = linearSearch(Colors, searchKey, ??); //?? is where I don't know what to enter

if (element != -1)  
{  
    printf("Found the word.\n");  
}  
else  
{  
    printf("Didn't find the word.\n");  
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what would the declaration look for the linearSearch function? I hope I provided enough information for this to be somewhat usable.

edit: Thanks all for the help, got the program working as intended.

Comment: You code doesn't look like code in this window. To fix that, edit your question (the link above) and then select your code and click the button with little 1s and 0s on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your linearSearch function to return the index of the search term in the array. Here is a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int linearSearch (const char **Array, const char *searchKey, int arraySize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(Array[i], searchKey) == 0)
            return i;
    }

    // We didn't find the searchKey in the Array
    return -1;
}

int main () {
    char *colors[] = { "red", "green", "blue" };

    int index = linearSearch (colors, "green", 3);

    if (index < 0) { // search string was not found
        printf("Search string not found!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("String %s found at index %d\n", colors[index], index);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

We use the strcmp() function to compare the strings. It returns zero if strings match and nonzero if they don't. To use it, you need to include the `string.h` header.

But, as others have suggested, you should use STL if you can.

Comment: I am so inept. How would I declare this function? That's what I'm having trouble with. After I would declare this, how would I use it?

I tried to use this with Tom Leys's suggestion. I am at a complete standstill.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Is it possible to look for "searchKey" instead of just one color, like the "green" in your example, or is there a limitation to what you can search for?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. You can search the array for any string you want(e.g. "I am a string"). If the array contains the string, this function will return the index of the string in the array. If the array doesn't contain the string, it will return -1. 
If you had a `char searchKey[] = "Find me"`; in your program, you could use that as the second argument of the function. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in my description. What I meant to ask was if I can have the user enter a word to look for in the array. Say I declare "char word;" then "printf("Enter the word to look for: \n");" then "scanf("%s", word);" -- Something like that. Then whatever was entered into "word" would be compared with the "colors" array. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But you should probably declare a char word[256] or char *word = (char *) malloc(256*sizeof(char)).
The `char word` would be only a single character.
Of course, you can use any size you think would be appropriate instead of 256.

Comment: Great, I got it working now by declaring "char word[size_here]" Thank you very much for the help, now I see how this works. :)

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend to learn about the C++ standard library, which would help you very much. For example,

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> words;
words.push_back("red");
words.push_back("blue");
words.push_back("green");

if (find(words.begin(), words.end(), "green") != words.end())
    cout << "found green!"
else
    cout << "didn't find it";
```

Why implement `linearSearch` yourself? c++ already has `std::find` which does it for you!
Moreover, if you use a `set` instead of a `vector`, you can now use `std::binary_search` which is O(log n) instead of O(n), since a set is sorted.

Comment: Here's a nice little intro to the STL (the C++ standard template library): http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/STL.html

Comment: Yeah, being a beginner doesn't mean you have to make things difficult for yourself. Make use of the standard library. That's what it's for. :)

Comment: I will be looking into the STL once I get a little bit more practice in with C++ in general. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

To declare an array of strings, use this syntax

```
 char *Colors[] = {"red", "green", "blue"};
```

This is an array of pointers to characters ("Hi" evaluates to a const char* pointing at the 'H'). The compiler will figure out how many elements are needed to store your array (hence the []) in this case it will always be of size 3.

Overall, I agree with rlbond's answer - you should use the STL.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need a two-dimensional array.

Here is a way to declare string arrays:

```
char* Colors[3] = {"red", "green", "blue"};
```

or

```
char* Colors[] = {"red", "green", "blue"}; // the compiler will figure out the size

int colors = sizeof(Colors)/sizeof(Colors[0]);
```

Right after experimenting with C++ you should learn to use STL.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.learning-computer-programming.blogspot.com/2007/06/string-searching-function-in-c.html) contains a string search function.  It should also give you insight into how to properly structure your character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use strings, and stay with char arrays you can use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) to compare 2 words.
The thing to remember with [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) is that it returns the index of where the word was found, so you if you want only to find words in the begining you do it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<SizeOfColorArray;i++)
{
    if(strcmp (MySearchTerm,colors[i]) == 0)
    {
        // it was  a match
        return i;
    }
}
```

Depending on what you are doing and how big your array is going to get, you should consider looking into having [hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the strings to increase preformance.